# rsh: Trouble connecting to Windows XP from Mac?

Tags: networking, windows-xp, remote

I want to run a batch script on a Windows XP machine from my Mac 10.6.6.  I installed Windows SFU, including Remote Shell Service, which I verified is started on the remote machine (http://screencast.com/t/uYDmpkUwJ4).  However, I'm unable to connect from my Mac, repeatedly getting timeouts ...

```
$ rsh 192.168.199.131 'cd C:\'
192.168.199.131: Operation timed out
$ telnet 192.168.199.131 4444
Trying 192.168.199.131...
Connected to 192.168.199.131.
Escape character is '^]'.
```

Notice that I'm able to telnet successfully into another service, so it's not a network issue.  I created a ~/.rhosts file that consists of ...

```
192.168.199.131 developer
```

Any ideas why I can't connect or what else I need to do to troubleshoot this issue? - Dave

Answer (score 1):

Do you *have* to use `rsh(1)`? It is unauthenticated, unencrypted, provides no message integrity or privacy, and is easily spoofed. Do you really want that for your Windows machine?

I suggest instead running an [ssh server on windows](http://lifehacker.com/205090/geek-to-live--set-up-a-personal-home-ssh-server); then you can just use `ssh(1)` and get strong authentication and encryption. *And* use modern tools.

Answer (score 0):

You're able to successfully telnet to port 4444, but rsh usually listens on port 514. Maybe your firewall config is letting 4444 through, but blocking 514?

You might try running [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) on the Windows machine, to watch the network traffic while you try to establish an rsh connection.